# Magic mouse not detected as magic mouse in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, mouse-scroll, magic-mouse

I have magic mouse (last generation) from Apple. It pairs with my laptop without problem and it works with clicking, right click and movement. But it doesn't scroll. The xinput command output is this:

`⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Ratón de xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ VGA Webcam                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

Do I have to install any driver or so to the scroll to begin working?

Thanks for your answers and your time!